# Interpolate covariance matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, interpolation, differential-geometry

I have measurements $z_i$ and associated covariance matrices $R_i$ separated in time by some sampling interval, and I want to interpolate between measurements.

For example, I have a measurement at time $t_1=1$:
$$
z_1=\begin{pmatrix}8794 \\ 4013 \\ 2998 \end{pmatrix}, R_1=\begin{pmatrix}77 & -60 & -45 \\ -60 & 103 & -36 \\ -45 & -36 & 125 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and another measurement at time $t_2=2$:
$$
z_2=\begin{pmatrix}8786 \\ 4043 \\ 2957 \end{pmatrix}, R_2=\begin{pmatrix}82 & -59 & -43 \\ -59 & 97 & -41 \\ -43 & -41 & 120 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I want to find $\tilde{z}$ and $\tilde{R}$ at time $t=1.5$. It's simple enough to compute $\tilde{z}$ using linear interpolation. My question is how do I interpolate the covariance matrices to get $\tilde{R}$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain how a single measurement might produce an entire covariance matrix?  How are these matrices estimated and what would be the purpose or intended interpretation of the interpolated values?

Comment: These measurements are from a sensor tracking the position of an object in 3D space. The sensor has known uncertainties. The measurement uncertainties increase as the object moves further away from the sensor. The purpose of interpolating the measurements is to synchronize them in time with measurements from other sources so that all the measurements can be fused together.

Comment: Thank you.  That raises many possibilities that are not apparent in the post itself.  It shows you don't have a single two-point interpolation problem: you are interpolating an entire series of data.  Second, if the measurement uncertainties (in the form of covariance matrices) are truly known, then why not just use the known formulas to compute them for the interpolated locations?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that although the sensor uncertainties are known, I don't have access to those values; I'm given only the measurements and the covariance matrix for each measurement. I know the standard formula $cov(x) = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (x_i - \bar{x})(x_i - \bar{x})^T$ to find the covariance of the entire data set, but I don't know how to go about computing the covariance for each interpolated point. Is this not possible to do without knowing the underlying sensor uncertainties? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Could you consider this an optimal transport problem in translation between Gaussians?

For example, the 2-Wasserstein distance interpolation is given in e.g. Mallasto, Anton, Augusto Gerolin, and Hà Quang Minh. 2022. “Entropy-Regularized 2-Wasserstein Distance between Gaussian Measures.” Information Geometry 5 (1): 289–323. https://doi.org/10.1007/s41884-021-00052-8.

$$
R_t = (1-t)^2 R_1 + t^2 R_2 + t(1-t) \left [ (R_1 R_2)^\frac{1}{2} + (R_2 R_1)^\frac{1}{2} \right ]
$$

Note that in this formula $t$ is fractional distance from $R_1$ to $R_2$ i.e. $t=0.5$ would be halfway.

Also notice that this requires the matrix root i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of interpolating covariance matrices is an [active area of research](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/74/4/697/7075308). Let's imagine that in your problem the covariance matrices are changing smoothly as given by an unknown function $f$ of time $t$, $f: t \to SPD$, where $SPD$ is the space of 3-by-3 covariance matrices (symmetric positive definite matrices). The goal is to find a function $g: t \to SPD$ that approximates $f$ as good as possible.

In this problem, there's at least two issues to consider:

1. Like any interpolation, we want our function $g$ to be close to the underlying unknown $f$ by some metric.
2. We want the output of $g$ to be a covariance matrix, that is, to belong to $SPD$.

Related to 1), like any interpolation problem, one option is to learn a function $g$ that minimizes **some distance** to the observations. For example, we could choose to fit a polynomial regression or a cubic spline to each element of the covariance matrices, and so interpolate each element separately.

However, since 2) is also a concern, we can't just do any interpolation like proposed above, because the result may not be a $SPD$ matrix. This is part of what makes the problem difficult: we need to choose our $g$ such that its result is an $SPD$ matrix.

Another issue that makes the problem difficult is that it is not obvious what **distance** we want to minimize between $g$ and the observed data. There are [many ways](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/18M1221084) in which we can measure the distance between covariance matrices.

Let's discuss some more options in light of what we discussed above.

One thing we could do is just do linear interpolation between neighboring matrices. E.g. we have the covariance at $t=1$ and $t=2$, denoted $\Sigma(1)$ and $\Sigma(2)$. Then, for $s \in [0,1]$, our interpolation is $\Sigma(1+s) = (1-s)\Sigma(1) + s\Sigma(2)$. The resulting matrix belongs to SPD, because the sum of two SPD matrices is SPD. However, this way to interpolate is completely *adhoc*, and may be far from the underlying $f$. Furthermore, the matrices that are interpolated this way will have a [larger determinant](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/18M1221084) than any of the the two observed matrices. This is related to the issue mentioned of what **distance** to use: our linear interpolation involves drawing the shortest line between the matrices in **Euclidean space**.

Another alternative is to do a geodesic interpolation between neighboring matrices. The intuition is exactly the same as above, but instead of drawing the shortest line in Euclidean space, we draw the shortest line in the $SPD$ manifold. This is what the other answer suggests: using geodesic interpolation in the SPDM manifold, using the Wasserstein metric. However, there are two issues with this solution. Related to point 1), we are doing nothing to approximate $f$ in particular, we are just drawing 'straight lines' between adjacent matrices. Further, there are different metrics or distances that can be used for covariance matrices. The Wasserstein metric is just one of them, and nothing says its geodesics should be good approximations to $f$.

Finally, the ideal thing would be to fit a curve to the data in the SPDM manifold. This is similar to doing a cubic spline interpolation, but the resulting interpolation should be in the SPDM manifold. Doing this is difficult though, and is why this is an active area of research. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4715771/948036) I answer a question proposing a way to do this type of regression in the $SPD$ manifold, but it is not guaranteed to work well, since we have to deform the space to apply it.

In sum, there is no best a-priori way to do this interpolation. Geodesic interpolation is an alternative, made easier by the Python package 'geomstats', but it may be way off the mark from the underlying $f$.